# Prove $Y_i = \frac{2X_i-i}{2n-i}, (1\le i \le 2n-1)$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

[image]

**$Y_i = \frac{2X_i-i}{2n-i}, (1\le i \le 2n-1)$**

*I have to prove that it is martingale*

**MY ATTEMPT :**

$X_i$ is the money I have after the i-th extraction which is equivalent to the number of white balls that I have up to the i-th extraction. I notice that $0 \le X_i \le i$

Looks like $X_i$ follows a hypergeometric distribution $X_i\sim $Hypergeometric$(2n,n,i)$ , $0\le i\le n$

Assuming the natural filtration $\mathcal F_i=\sigma(X_1,...,X_i)$ I have already proven adaptability and finite mean. I am having trouble with the martingale property

$E[Y_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]= \frac{1}{2n-i-1}(2E[X_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]-i-1)= ?$

I am stuck here,  but I cannot apply the formula for the mean with the conditioning on the way and I don't think $X_{i+1}$ is independent from $\mathcal F_i$ since the money I have up to the $(i+1)$-th extraction depends on how much money I have up to the $i$-th extraction.  Even if I am wrong and there is independence, using the formula for the mean of a hypergeometric distribution yields $0$:

$E[Y_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]= \frac{1}{2n-i-1}(2E[X_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]-i-1)=  \frac{1}{2n-i-1}(2E[X_{i+1}]-i-1)= \frac{1}{2n-i-1}(2E[X_{i+1}]-i-1)=\frac{1}{2n-i-1}(2(i+1)n/2n -i-1)=0$

**What I am missing and how do I proceed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you only need to do is calculate $E(X_{i+1}|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i}))$. Now notice that if $X_{i}$ is known, then you can calculate $E(X_{i+1}|X_{1},...,X_{i})=E(X_{i+1}|X_{i})$. This is because the information $X_{i}$ specifies the number of white balls and number of black balls that are left before the $i+1$-th draw. So, conditioning on that, you can easily find the expected value of $X_{i+1}$.

So,

Suppose $X_{i}=k$ (here you could additionally  assume that $X_{1}=k_{1},...X_{i-1}=k_{i-1}$ as you know $\sigma(X_{1},..,X_{i})$ but those informations will not matter to us in the calculation) . Then, there are $n-k$ white balls left and $n-i+k$ black balls left.

So $P(X_{i+1}=k+1|X_{i}=k)=\frac{n-k}{2n-i}$ and $P(X_{i+1}=k|X_{i}=k)=\frac{n-i+k}{2n-i}$

Hence $E(X_{i+1}|X_{i}=k)=\dfrac{(k+1)(n-k)+k(n-i+k)}{2n-i}$

Now just verify that

$\displaystyle E(Y_{i+1}|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i}))=\frac{2E(X_{i+1}|X_{i}=k)-(i+1)}{2n-i-1}=\frac{2k-i}{2n-i}=\frac{2X_{i}-i}{2n-i}=Y_{i}$

To elaborate,

\begin{align}E(Y_{i+1}|X_{i}=k)&=\dfrac{\frac{2(k+1)(n-k)+k(n-i+k)}{2n-i}-(i+1)}{2n-i-1}\\\\
&=\frac{2kn-2k^{2}+2n-2k+2kn-2ki-2k^{2}-2ni-2n-i^{2}-i}{(2n-i)(2n-i-1)}\\\\
&=\frac{2k(2n-i-1)-i(2n-i-1)}{(2n-i)(2n-i-1)}\\\\
&=\frac{(2n-i-1)(2k-i)}{(2n-i)(2n-i-1)}\\\\
&=\frac{2k-i}{2n-i}\\\\
&=\frac{2X_{i}-i}{2n-i}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Why do you only consider $P(X_{i+1}=k+1|X_{i}=k)$ and $P(X_{i+1}=k|X_{i}=k)=$, when the conditioning is with respect to the whole $\sigma (X_1,...X_i)$? I don't get how  you got rid of $X_1, ...X_{i-1}$ in the computation of $E(Y_{i+1}|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i}))$

Comment: I have added a line just k=now

Comment: @some_math_guy Just observe that you can additionally assume $X_{1}=k_{1},...,X_{i-1}=k_{i-1},X_{i}=k$. But the other informations will  not impact on the conditional expectation or any of our calculation.

Comment: There is an embedded Markovian property that is causing this. $P(X_{i+1}=m|X_{1}=k_{1},...,X_{i}=k_{i})=P(X_{i+1}=m|X_{i}=k_{i})$.

Comment: @some_math_guy For a similar situation, consider a simple symmetric random walk on $\Bbb{Z}$. Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ (which denotes your position at time $n$) is a martingale. Here $X_{k}$ are iid symmetric bernoulli $\frac{1}{2}$ variates. Now if $S_{n+1}$ actually only depends on your current position $S_{n}$ and you can forget about the past. But as I said, it does not matter, you can assume all information upto $X_{i}$, i.e. $\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i})$ . It still won't affect any calculation as you only need the number of white and black balls left which is specified by $X_{i}$.

Comment: I know that one computes $ E[X|Y]$, by first computing $ h(y)=E[X|Y=y]$ and then $E[X|Y] =h(Y)$ and that  $ E[X|Y]$ is shorthand for $ E[X|\sigma(Y)]$.  So in the case   $ E[X|\sigma(Y_1,..,Y_n)]$ is that the same as $E[X|Y_1,...,Y_n]$ ? and if so one does the same to compute it:  first $ h(y_1,...y_n)=E[X|Y_1=y_1,...,Y_n=y_n] $ and then $E[X|Y_1,...,Y_n] =h(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ . Another thing was I right that $X_i$ is a Hypergeometric$(2n,n,i)$?

Comment: It is a short hand yes.  And yes, $X_{i}$ has Hypergeometric$(2n,n,i)$ distribution. @some_math_guy

Comment: @some_math_guy Please accept answers to your questions as well otherwise it remains in the unanswered section. You have not accepted answers in quite a few of your last problems.

Comment: Sure Do yo know where I can find I proof of that Markovian property? Or is it just the definition that you apply provided that you are able to identify a Markov chain?

Comment: It makes sense that we don't need the information before the present to compute $E[X_{i+1}|X_1,....X_i]$ I just wonder if it can be proved formarly, that is by writing something where it can be seen explicitly that they disappear operationally when one consider them initially

Comment: Suppose all the random variables are deifned on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ What does conditioning on $\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i})$ mean? It precisely means that you know everything about $X_{1},...,X_{i}$. So you can consider their values to be fixed. That is, you are calculating the random variable $E(X_{i+1}|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i}))(\omega)$. As soon as an omega is fixed, you have $X_{m}(\omega)=k_{m}$. So $ E(X_{i+1}|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i}))(\omega)$ is the hilbert space projection to the subspace $L^{2}(\Omega,\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{i}),P)$ of the $L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. @some_math_guy

Comment: @some_math_guy So it can directly be verified using the theory of linear regression that in the case that a "conditional" density (whehter with respect to the counting measure or the Lebesgue Measure) exists, then the expectation with respect to that density is the random variable (vector in the subspace which minimizes the distance to $X_{i}$.  This is all just an elaborate way of saying that if you are given $X_{m}=k_{m}$. Then the conditional density only depends on what the value of $X_{i}$ is .

Comment: @some_math_guy As a general advice, conditional expectation and conditional probability are two things where it is very very easy to make conceptual mistakes. So it is often wise to not overthink. For example in this scenario. You see that once $X_{1}=k_{1},...,X_{i}=k_{i}$ , then it is immediate that $X_{i+1}$ is either $k_{i}$ or $k_{i}+1$ . So, it suffices to only be concerned about $k_{i}$ and show that conditioned on the information, $E(Y_{i+1}|X_{1},...,X_{i})=E(Y_{i+1}|X_{i})=X_{i}$.

Comment: @some_math_guy In particular as I said, in case of $L^{2}$ random variables, $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ is the vector in $L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P)$ which is closest to $X$. In otherwords, it is the orthogonal projection of $X\in L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to the subspace $L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P)$. So to prove it in the fullest rigor and generality one can use the theory of linear regression to show that the expectation with respect to the conditional density gives us the orthogonal projection.

Comment: If you have time , could you please check this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728653/prove-z-i-frac2n-i2n-i-1y-i2-frac12n-i-1-1-le-i-le-2n-2-is-a?  It's the second part of this question and it actually more difficult.