# Prove $Z_i = \frac{2n-i}{2n-i-1}Y_i^2 - \frac1{2n-i-1} (1 \le i \le 2n-2) $ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, martingales

[image: ![enter image description here]

**$Y_i = \frac{2X_i-i}{2n-i}, (1\le i \le 2n-1)$**
**$Z_i = \frac{2n-i}{2n-i-1}Y_i^2 - \frac1{2n-i-1} (1 \le i \le 2n-2) $**

*I have to prove that $Y_i$ and $Z_i$  are martingales and calculate the mean and variance of $X_i$*

**MY ATTEMPT :**

Here it was proven that $Y_i$ is a martingale  [Prove $Y_i = \frac{2X_i-i}{2n-i}, (1\le i \le 2n-1)$ is a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728586/prove-y-i-frac2x-i-i2n-i-1-le-i-le-2n-1-is-a-martingale/4728601?noredirect=1#comment10022158_4728601)

As in that question:

$X_i$ is the money I have after the i-th extraction which is equivalent to the number of white balls that I have up to the i-th extraction. I notice that $0 \le X_i \le i$

Looks like $X_i$ follows a hypergeometric distribution $X_i\sim $Hypergeometric$(2n,n,i)$ , $0\le i\le n$

Assuming the natural filtration $\mathcal F_i=\sigma(X_1,...,X_i)$ I have already proven adaptability and finite mean of $Z_i$. For the martingale property

$E[Z_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]= \frac{2n-i-1}{2n-i-2}E[Y_{i+1}^2|\mathcal F_i] - \frac1{2n-i-2} $

To compute $E[Y_{i+1}^2|\mathcal F_i]$ I am unsure if the same simplified formula holds as in the non-conditioning case:

$E[Y_{i+1}^2|\mathcal F_i]=E[Y_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]^2 +Var[Y_{i+1}|\mathcal F_i]\tag{*} ? $

**If this is true, how do I compute that variance?** I am not arriving to the answer. The problem did warn that it was a complicated calculation, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the exact same question when it comes to showing that $Z_{i}$ is a martingale. If you know $X_{i}=k$, then $E(X_{i+1}^{2}|X_{i}=k)= (k+1)^{2}P(X_{i+1}=k+1|X_{i}=k)+k^{2}P(X_{i+1}=k|X_{i}=k)$. And I already showed you what $P(X_{i+1}=k+1|X_{i}=k)$ etc are.

To quote the other question directly

> $P(X_{i+1}=k+1|X_{i}=k)=\frac{n-k}{2n-i}$ and
> $P(X_{i+1}=k|X_{i}=k)=\frac{n-i+k}{2n-i}$

So I'll not even bother to do the verification that $Z_{i}$ is a martingale and you should verify it yourself.

Now, as to calculating the mean and variance, observe that since $Y_{i}$ is a martingale $E(Y_{i+1}|\mathcal{F}_{i})=Y_{i}$ . Hence $E(Y_{i+1})=E(E(Y_{i+1}|\mathcal{F}_{i}))=E(Y_{i})$

Thus, the expectations remains constant.

Thus $\displaystyle\frac{2E(X_{i})-i}{2n-i}=E(Y_{i})=E(Y_{1})=\frac{2E(X_{1})-1}{2n-1}$ .

Now calculate $E(X_{1})=1\cdot\frac{n}{2n}+0\cdot\frac{n}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$  which is just your expected profit after first draw and use the above relation to find $E(X_{i})$.

Hence, you now know $E(Y_{i})$ . Now as $Z_{i}$ is a martingale, $E(Z_{i})=E(Z_{1})$. From  this, you can find a relation between $E(Y_{1}^{2})$ and $E(Y_{i}^{2})$ and use that to find $E(Y_{i}^{2})$ in terms of $E(Y_{1}^{2})$ which is easily calculable. Now you expand $Y_{i}^{2}$ out and use everything that you have calculated to find $E(X_{i}^{2})$ in terms of $E(X_{1}^{2})$ and $E(X_{1})$ and then find the variance by using $Var(X_{i})=E(X_{i}^{2})-(E(X_{i}))^{2}$.

Expect to do some long and tedious but elementary calculations though. It is often the case that in such questions, it essentially becomes a middle school level tedious algebra question where you have some equations given and you have to find a certain value by eliminating variables.

Comment: Ok, so working directly with the square is the way to go. By the way is the conditional expectation formula (*) valid? I couldn't find it in my books. I know that  the definition is analogous to the non-conditiong case , though:$ Var [X|\mathcal F]=E[(X - [E|\mathcal F])^2|\mathcal F ]$

Comment: @some_math_guy Yes it is valid. I don't know why you couldn't find it in your books. It's a famous formula. Maybe it is left as an excercise. It has been asked several times in this site. Maybe you can take it as an easy excercise and verify it.

Comment: @some_math_guy Sorry. It is valid, but I shouldn't say that it is famous. I mistook it for something else. It is practically a useless formula and just follows by expaning the right hand side and using the tower property.

Comment: Then it makes sense why is not in my books, I thing the famous one you should have been thinking about was perhaps  $Var[X]=E[Var(X|\mathcal F)]+Var(E[X|\mathcal F])$. Funny that (*) is useless as in the non-conditioning case is actually more usefull than the definition

Comment: @some_math_guy Yeah exactly lol.

Comment: If you've got a minute, I'd really could use you help here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729087/show-qi-mathbb-p-exists-m-infty-eta-m-0-eta-0-i-is-a-ma    I am completely lost here