# Show $Q(\eta_n) := \mathbb P \{\exists m < \infty : \eta_m = 0 |\eta_0 = \eta_n\}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, martingales

I am trying to solve this problem

> Let $\eta_n$ be a homogeneous Markov chain on the countable state
> space $S : =\{ 0,1,2,...\}$ and
>
> $\mathcal F_n := \sigma(\eta_j; 0 \le j \le n), n \ge 0$ its natural
> filtration. For $i \in S$ denote by $Q(i)$ the probability that the
> Markov chain starting from site $i$ ever reaches the point $0 \in S$:
>
> $Q(i) := \mathbb P \{\exists m  < \infty : \eta_m = 0 |\eta_0 = i\}$
>
> Prove that
> $Z_n := Q(\eta_n)$ is an $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\ge 0}$-martingale

I read the definition of Markov chain, transition probability and homogeneous Markov chain, apart from that I don't know much about Markov chains. Still I am not making much sense of this problem

1. To prove the martngale property, I don't know how to manage $Q$ in $E[Q(\eta_{n+1})|\mathcal F_n)]=E[\mathbb P \{\exists m  < \infty : \eta_m = 0 |\eta_0 = \eta_{n+1}\}|\mathcal F_n)]$

How  am I supposed to compute the probability of a probability(That is why I need to compute the expectation I guess) or equivalently the expectation of a probability? $Q(\eta_n)$ does not seem like a random variable

Moreover I am not sure how to check the other conditions either. $Z_n$ does not seem adapted as it depends on future events, i.e. on some $m>n+1$, i.e. $\eta_m$ which is not $\mathcal F_n$-measurable.  I am not sure how to check $E[|Z_n|]< \infty $ either

2. I am not sure if this makes a lot of sense: $ Q(\eta_{n+1})= \mathbb P \{\exists m  < \infty : \eta_m = 0 |\eta_0 = \eta_{n+1}\}$ then $n+1=0 $

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem? When you are having this much confusion, then it is wise to state the source of the problem in your question.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Source of the problem: Problem 2.13 in https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mb13434/hw2_mt20z.pdf

Comment: This is actually a very conceptual problem. (+1) I have provided a detailed solution. I hope the problem gets upvoted.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks I appreciate the effort, thanks for the reference too, it looks interesting. Let me process this and get back to you later

Comment: Take your time and make sure you digest my solution properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probabilities of the form $P(\text{we reach state i starting from j in finite time})$ are known as hitting probabilities.

To shorten the notation, let me use $H_{j}^{i}=P(\text{we reach state i starting from j in finite time})$

First of all, adaptability is not a problem. For $\eta_{n}$, $H_{\eta_{n}}^{0}$ is a random variable depending only on $\eta_{n}$. That is, for any $\omega$, $\eta_{n}(\omega)$ is fixed and $H_{\eta_{n}(\omega)}^{0}$ is a fixed real number (a probability).

When in doubt, always try to relate it to a Simple Symmetric Random Walk scenario.

> If you have trouble understanding the above point, then consider two
> identical copies of the markov chain $\{\eta_{n}\}$. When an $\omega$
> realizes in this first/original markov chain, then you know what $\eta_{1},\eta_{2},....$ in this chain
> Suppose $\eta_{n}(\omega)=k$. Then you go to the other copy of the
> markov chain and you assign $Q(\eta_{n}(\omega))$ the value $H_{k}^{0}$,
> where $H_{k}^{0}$ is the probability that in this markov chain you hit
> $0$ in finite time starting at state $k$. Which is just a fixed real number which does not depend
> on what $\eta_{j},\,j\neq k$ was or is for the original markov chain.

Suppose $(p_{ij})_{i,j\in S}$ is the transition matrix.

Now suppose $\eta_{1}=k_{1},...,\eta_{n}=k_{n}$

Then $E(H_{\eta_{n+1}}^{0}|\sigma(\eta_{1},...,\eta_{n}))=E(H_{\eta_{n+1}}^{0}|\eta_{1}=k_{1},...,\eta_{n}=k_{n}))$

But what is this?

See that conditioned on $\eta_{n}=k_{n}$,  $H_{\eta_{n+1}}^{0}$ takes the value $H_{j}^{0}$ if the markov chain goes from $k_{n}$ at n-th stage to $j$ at $n+1$-th stage. But what is the probability of going to $j$ from $k_{n}$?. It is precisely $p_{k_{n}j}$

So what is the conditional expectation?

It is precisely  \begin{align}E(H_{\eta_{n+1}}^{0}|\eta_{1}=k_{1},...,\eta_{n}=k_{n}))&=E(H_{\eta_{n+1}}^{0}|\eta_{n}=k_{n})\\\\
&=\sum_{j\in S}p_{k_{n}j}H_{j}^{0}\end{align}

Now it can be shown for a markov chain, that $\displaystyle H_{i}^{j}=\sum_{k\in S}p_{ik}H_{k}^{j}$.

See [Norris' Markov chains](https://mathematicaster.org/teaching/lcs22/norris_markov.pdf) Theorem 1.3.2 page 13 for a proof. (I'd recommend getting a djvu version if you can for best reading)

Thus $E(H_{\eta_{n+1}}^{0}|\eta_{1}=k_{1},...,\eta_{n}=k_{n}))=H_{k_{n}}^{0}=Q(\eta_{n})$

That's it.

Comment: Can the $E|Z_n|\le  \infty$ martingale condition be deduced from this?

Comment: @some_math_guy The expectations will be bounded by $1$ as $Q(\eta_{n})$ itself is after all a "probability". So $|Q(\eta_{n})|\leq 1$ always.

Comment: @some_math_guy See, one usually assumes that you have seen markov chains in a basic probability course. But even then, it is not a necessity in understanding martingale theory. But if your instructor feels like it, then they may give some problems from markov chains. So as I said, it is a better idea to read the first chapter from the book I suggested to atleast get your definitions of markov chain right. Or you may see a few lectures from a markov chains course on youtube.

Comment: @some_math_guy Personally,I would say that this is a better strategy than trying to understand markov chains from a discussion in a "comment section" or even a site like MSE. You should read/study a base material by yourself. After that, MSE users will try their best to clear your doubts. If I was in a situation as you, I would either exclude all problems related to markov chains or I would try to get a very basic and overall intuitive understanding of markov chains by reading an introductory chapter of a book or by watching some videos/lectures and they are in abundance in youtube.

Comment: Yeah I will do that,thanks for the suggestion. Since now I am kind of pressed with time, only 5 days to go for the exam and the other half of the course which i still have to study is Large deviation theory :(, I think I will postpone problems like this one

Answer (score 0):

Notice, by the Markov structure, $$ Q(i) = \Pi(i \to 0) + \sum_{j \neq 0} \Pi(i \to j) Q(j).$$ In words, the chance to get to $0$ from $i$ can be decomposed as the chance of getting there in one step, plus the chance of getting somewhere else in $1$ step, and then getting to zero from there.

But note that $Q(0) = 1,$ since if $\eta_0 = 0,$ then there does exist an $m < \infty$ such that $\eta_m = 0$ (namely $m = 0$). This means that we can write the expression as $$ Q(i) = \sum_{j} \Pi(i \to j) Q(j).$$

(This last observation is crucial. If you were studying $R(i) := P(\exists m: 0 < m < \infty, \eta_m = 0| \eta_0 = i),$ then the martingale result may have failed for dynamics with $R(0) < 1.$ As an exercise, find a dynamics for which this $R(\eta_n)$ is not a martingale, and also show that $R(\eta_n)$ is always a supermartingale.)

Now, by definition, $$ \mathbb{E}[Q(\eta_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_{n}] = \sum_j P(\eta_{n+1} = j|\mathcal{F}_n) Q(j) = \sum_j \Pi(\eta_n \to j) Q(j) = Q(\eta_n),$$ where I've used the Markovianity in the second equality.

(Of course, you'll also have to check adaptation and integrability, but these are trivial)

Comment: I guess in your notation $\Pi$ is the transition probability?

Comment: So I am trying to understand Markov chains, in a Markov chain 1)  You move only from one state to the  one of the 2 neighboring states, right? That is for instance from state 4 we can go only to states 3 and 5 ? I am picturing the chain as the non -negative integers. 2) But are transitions from a state k to the same state k allowed? Meaning there is no transition?  That would be different than a simple random walk I guess, which is always in the move.  3) These 2 remarks have to be correct I guess otherwise I would not make sense of $\Pi (0\to 0)$.

Comment: And so isn't $\Pi(i \to 0)=\Pi(0 \to 0) + \Pi(1 \to 0) $? Since there are two ways to step to 0: being already there and not moving ot transitioning from 1 to 0

Comment: @some_math_guy If you are trying to understand markov chains, then why don't you read the first chapter of the book I referred to?. In a markov chain you move to any state $i$ from a state $j$ with probability $p_{ij}$ . The matrix $(p_{ij})$ is called the transition matrix. If the probabilities are $0$ then you can intuitively think that you cannot move to a particular state. The case you are referring to is when $p_{4,m}=0$ for all $m\neq 3,5$ and that need not be the case.

Comment: @some_math_guy If you do not know markov chains then what is even the point of trying to "solve" this problem which depends highly on your understanding of what a markov chain is.  If you are trying to learn martingale theory, then you need not know jack about markov chains and you can still learn and understand almost all of the theory.

Comment: @some_math_guy In any case, one usually takes a markov chain(elementary stochastic processes) course simultaneously while learning martingale theory if they are not familiar with it. In any case, a martingale is not necessarily a markov chain and neither is a martingale necessarily a markov chain. It's just that understanding each of the topics helps in understanding the other in a better and more conceptual way. But as I said, one can learn martingale theory without knowning markov chains also. It's just that in markov chains, one really sees concrete applications of conditional probability.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron We are using the notes and problem sets from the website I linked in a course of Martingale theory, at assumes only some measure-theoretic probability and the associated notes which contain  a summary of the required probability don't mention anything about Markov chains. However most problems didn't require nothing more than the definition (Markovian property) like the simple symmetric  random walk or the drawing of balls without replacement